# What Movie Quote Am I?

Tags: word, rebus, movies

Each of the 4 pictures below represents one word in a famous movie quote. The pictures (and thus, the words) are in order from left to right.

Once you get the 4 words indicated by the pictures below, then you will use those words to derive the first 4 words of the movie quote.

At that point, you can use a search engine to easily find the rest of the quote (if needed).

In the 4th picture, those are not "slices" because slices are wider.

The word indicated by the 2nd pic is an 8-letter adjective.

**Can you finish the quote and find what movie it's from?**

[image]

Comment: My wife thinks those are slices. I think half a pie is a slice. Perspective!

Comment: I assumed the pictures were meant to be read left-to-right, so that hint isn't very helpful. That said, I came up with "Lollipop low sodium hills dessert," but I don't know what movie that's from.

Comment: @Rhettorical No need to assume. Check out hint #1.  :)   -- Extra hint: It's not "low sodium" because that's 2 words.

Comment: @JLee The left-to-right reading order isn't so much a hint if you're from the Western world (where left-to-right is assumed). You're saying this is a fairly well-known quote, and those four pictures represent the first four words?

Comment: @Rhettorical It is a hint, since there are 4! = 24 ways to arrange the 4 pics, but I told you what order they were in. Once you get the 4 words indicated by the pictures, then you will use those words to derive the first 4 words of the movie quote. Yes, the word you get for the 1st pic will become the first word of the quote, and the word you get for the 2nd pic will become the 2nd word of the quote, etc. But the way you go from the pic word to the quote word...that's the core of the puzzle.

Comment: @JLee Ok, I see. I suppose you could have been more devious and switched up the order. (please don't)

Comment: Well lollipop saltless hills sliver. I'm sorry but it does not ring a bell ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is:

> "I ate his liver with some fava beans and a nice chianti" (from The Silence of the Lambs)

Why? Because, the pictures are (from left to right):

> Lollipop
>  Saltless
>  Hills
>  Slivers

Then we just need to:

> Remove any characters from each word that appear more than once.

Comment: +1 Excellent! I was wondering how many hints I'd need to give. I guess no more! The amount of puzzle-solving talent on this site never ceases to amaze me!

Answer (score 2):

> Switch off mobile phone

is the result when doing a reverse google image search. Probably not the correct answer but pretty funny given this is related to cinema :-)